# Android app hangs after subsequent call to startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Not sure if this is know behavior or what, but here's the logical flow:

1. User opens app
2. Pulls nav drawer out, clicks profile pic to change it
3. Gallery intent pops up, user picks image, everything works fine
4. Subsequent attempt to open gallery works fine, upon choosing picture, application hangs

onResume() is not called, neither is onActivityResult(). I even commented out all the code in onActivityResult and it still happens. Any ideas what would cause this?

Here is code from onCreate() in the main activity

```
    ImageButton profilePictureButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.change_profile_picture);
    profilePictureButton.requestFocus();
    profilePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");

            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
```

And here's the handler:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == 1) {
            ImageView view = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_picture));

            if(data != null) {
                /*Picasso.with(this).load(data.getData()).into(view);

                UsersCache.getInstance().GetUser("", new Response.Listener<UserItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(UserItem response) {
                        String pictureName = response.username + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                        String url = "<redacted>";

                        JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            requestBody.put("profilePicture", "<redacted>/media/profile_pictures/" + pictureName);
                        } catch(JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return;
                        }

                        FlareJsonObjectRequest request = new FlareJsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, url, requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                String tet = null;
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                String tet = null;
                            }
                        });

                        new AmazonS3Uploader(data.getData(), "profile_pictures/" + pictureName);

                        VolleyQueue.getInstance().getQueue().add(request);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        String tet = null;
                    }
                });*/
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: Is "gallery" an Activity inside your codebase, or is it in another application?

Comment: Just the standard gallery intent, as shown.

Comment: @AbdulFatir check it out

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the read access permission in Manifest -

```
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Nope it's there, like I said, it works fine when you set your profile picture it the first time. It does NOT work when you try and do it right after.

Comment: Are you getting any crash, then please share the crash report. It will help a lot, and if possible share your activity class.